# Why is the probability different? We launch two dice

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We launch two dice with faces $1 , 2, \dots, 6$, one black, one white.

I want to calculate the probability that the sum of the two dice's faces is $\geq 11$.

If I choose the main set as $\Omega = \{ (i,j) : i , j \in [[1,6]] \}$ we clearly have $|\Omega|  = 6^2 = 36$
and the only couples that give us the sum $\geq 11$ are $(6,5)$, $(5,6)$, $(6,6)$ so the probability is $3/36 = 1/12$.

Everything is good so far.

Now lets see if we take $\Omega$ as the set that contains the sums of the faces.

$\Omega = \{2,3 , \dots, 11, 12\}$ so $|\Omega|=11$.
So the probability that the sum of the two faces is $\geq 11$ is $2/11$ (either the sum is $11$ or $12$).

But $2/11 \neq 1/12$. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The 11 cases in your second choice for $\Omega$ are  not equally likely. That's the whole point of the question.

Comment: chance to draw 2 is not the same as the chance to draw 3. your sums of the faces Omega is not in equal probability for each outcome.

Comment: in other words.. your "set" should contain {2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5....}

Answer (score 1):

I forgot that the relation P=  Card(event)/Card(Omega) requires that the event set has a uniform probability (sorry for my english im french)

Comment: ..Imagine there is 50% to win the lottery {win,lose} :).